# Dispatch an action only once that too if an async action has successfully fetched data and updated the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect, redux-saga

I want to dispatch an action only once but payload I pass to this action depends on results fetched by another async action that also runs only once.

```
const data=useSelector(aSelector.getData);
const selectedData=useSelector(bSelector.getSelectedData);

React.useEffect(()=>{
       dispatch(sagaAction.fetchData());   //this is async action that sets state which I use to dispatch below action
       dispatch(simpleAction.setSelectedData(data.name);  //This action sets state which is used as selectedData.this action should run once when above action has succesfully fetched data .Both actions should run only once 

})
```

Code above is not exactly right. It is only to give an idea what I want to achieve and how I thought I could do it.Is there any sound way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to separate these into two different `useEffect` hooks and take advantage of `useEffect`'s dependency parameter like so:

```
const data = useSelector(aSelector.getData);
const selectedData = useSelector(bSelector.getSelectedData);

React.useEffect(() => {
  // The [data] array below tells React to run this useEffect when the
  // component mounts and then again any time `data` changes, 
  // but then we use the `if` statement to make sure
  // we only run the dispatch when `data` exists
  if(data) {
    dispatch(simpleAction.setSelectedData(data.name);
  }
}, [data])

React.useEffect(() => {
  // The empty array below tells React to only run this `useEffect` once when the component mounts
  dispatch(sagaAction.fetchData());
}, [])
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. thanks a lot